# Exception thrown: Access violation reading location

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, sse

I am using a sample code from an old book but the code is written as inline assembly!
I created a new console app project. added MASM dependancy and the file type is Microsoft Macro Assembler.

I keep getting this error whether it's targeted for 32 or 64!

```
=>MOVAPS XMM0, [esi]
Exception thrown at 0x00D4101C in Project3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF
Exception thrown at 0x00000000004F101C in Project3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

asmcode.asm

```
.model flat,c
.const
 .data
A     dd 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4 
B     dd 1,2,3,4


 .code
main PROC
        MOV esi, A
        MOV edi, B
        MOVAPS XMM0, [esi]
        MOVUPS XMM1, [edi]
        ADDPS XMM0, XMM1
        MOVAPS XMM1, XMM0
        MOVAPS[esi], XMM0
        MOVUPS[edi], XMM1
        
main endp
 end
```

**Any idea  why it's not working?
When I try to get the address of A and B instead of the address of the registers esi and edi, it works**

so this works

```
MOVAPS XMM0, [A]
MOVUPS XMM1, [B]
```

FYI The code works with the registers in inline assembly

Comment: Use `mov esi, offset A` or `lea esi, A` to load the address, not the value.

Comment: Thanks that did it, but i dont understand why it didnt work? shouldnt the [esi] load the address of the value stored in it?

Comment: The `movaps xmm0, [esi]` wants an address in `esi` as it is loading from memory. The `mov esi, A` however loaded the first item from your array (the `0.1`) and not its address.

Comment: Also don't forget to `align 16` before your data if you want to make sure it's aligned for `movaps` (or a memory source for `addps`).  You could `movups xmm0, [B]` / `addps xmm0, [A]`.

Comment: yeah I have the data aligned for the first vector